# Liferay - Error while trying to create a JournalArticle programmatically

Tags: liferay, portlet

I am very new to liferay and everyday during my learning period I face all kind of problems that I face and solve as challenges! However I am facing a new one that is driving me crazy and I would like to see if I could get some help or guidance here at the development forum, so here is my problem:

I am trying to create a new JournalArticle programmatically, I have a default JournalArticle where I get most of the stuff I need, so I will copy it and then I will change some of the JournalArticle attributes. I am using the addArticle method from JournalArticleServiceUtil so, JournalArticleServiceUtil.addArticle(..... I have all the parameter filled in correctly (I hope) but I am getting an error related with Locale (com.liferay.portal.LocaleException), Locale is only used on the Map in the Title and Description, I can see that on the method summary ( Map titleMap, Map descriptionMap..... ), I think I have a valid Map but its not working and the error message iI receive is -> null.... The StackTrace is also not very usefull.

**Here is a sample of my code:**

```
final JournalArticle article = JournalArticleServiceUtil.getArticle(groupId, defaultArticleId);
        ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(JournalArticle.class.getName(), actionRequest);

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

        try
        {
            String[] titleMapLanguageIds = {"en_US"}, titleMapValues = {"Title in US"};
            String[] descriptionMapLanguageIds = {"en_US"}, descriptionMapValues = {"Description in US"};

            Map<Locale, String> titleMap = LocalizationUtil.getLocalizationMap(titleMapLanguageIds, titleMapValues);
            Map<Locale, String> descriptionMap = LocalizationUtil.getLocalizationMap(descriptionMapLanguageIds, descriptionMapValues);

            final JournalArticle newArticle = JournalArticleServiceUtil.addArticle(
                    article.getGroupId(),
                    article.getClassNameId(), 
                    article.getClassPK(), 
                    "", true,
                    titleMap, 
                    descriptionMap, 
                    article.getContent(),
                    article.getType(), 
                    article.getStructureId(), 
                    article.getTemplateId(), 
                    article.getLayoutUuid(),
                    now.get(Calendar.MONTH), now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), now.get(Calendar.YEAR), now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), now.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true,
                    now.get(Calendar.MONTH), now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), now.get(Calendar.YEAR),now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), now.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                    true, true, 
                    article.getSmallImage(), 
                    article.getSmallImageURL(), 
                    null, 
                    new HashMap<String, byte[]>(), 
                    article.getUrlTitle(), 
                    serviceContext);
```

**Here is a relevant part (that I think) of the stackTrace:**

com.liferay.portal.LocaleException
.
.
.
at com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.JournalArticleServiceUtil.addArticle(JournalArticleServiceUtil.java:78)

**And here is the full stackTrace:**

```
com.liferay.portal.LocaleException
at com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.impl.JournalArticleLocalServiceImpl.validate(JournalArticleLocalServiceImpl.java:3445)
at com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.impl.JournalArticleLocalServiceImpl.validate(JournalArticleLocalServiceImpl.java:3549)
at com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.impl.JournalArticleLocalServiceImpl.addArticle(JournalArticleLocalServiceImpl.java:192)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:122)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:71)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.PACLAdvice.invoke(PACLAdvice.java:51)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:211)
at $Proxy205.addArticle(Unknown Source)
at com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.impl.JournalArticleServiceImpl.addArticle(JournalArticleServiceImpl.java:61)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:122)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:71)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.PACLAdvice.invoke(PACLAdvice.java:51)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:211)
at $Proxy206.addArticle(Unknown Source)
at com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.JournalArticleServiceUtil.addArticle(JournalArticleServiceUtil.java:78)
at com.esa.action.partner.CreatePartnerAction.createPartner(CreatePartnerAction.java:102)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.callActionMethod(LiferayPortlet.java:153)
at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.callActionMethod(MVCPortlet.java:250)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.processAction(LiferayPortlet.java:80)
at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.processAction(MVCPortlet.java:220)
at com.esa.action.partner.CreatePartnerAction.processAction(CreatePartnerAction.java:76)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:70)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:111)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:530)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:534)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:579)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.processAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:294)
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processPortletRequest(LayoutAction.java:944)
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:688)
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:249)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:176)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:560)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:537)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:294)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:138)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:335)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:123)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:294)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:241)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:246)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:80)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:216)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:187)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:167)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:167)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:187)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Can anyone please help me out here? Or point me in the right direction?

Please let me know if I can provide any more information that can help solve this issue.

Many thanks,
Cipriano

Comment: What version of Liferay are you using?

Answer (score 0):

A quick skim of the code indicates that it is being caused by the `JournalArticle` content.

The article's default locale for its content is not an "available locale". Check your portal settings in `portal.properties` or `portal-ext.properties` for the key `locales` to make sure the article's default locale is listed.

Comment: To clarify, it is not the `title` or `description` that you create but the `content` you're pass directly from the `article` object that is causing the issue.